# Install system-wide PEAR on Debian Lenny

Tags: php, debian, debian-lenny, pear

I've installed PEAR on Debian Lenny using `apt-get install php-pear`, it was installed in `/usr/share/php`

When I try to install anything using `pear install <package>` the PEAR folder is created under current user home directory and separate copy of pear is installed there.

I ended up by installing local copy of PEAR for one of the users like this:
http://kuziel.info/log/archives/2006/04/01/Installation-of-local-PEAR-repository

Is any way to tell pear to install packages to system-wide repository in `/usr/share/php`? What is the recommended way of using system-wide PEAR copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be mistaken, but simply running `pear install` as root should do exactly what you want.

Comment: Unfortunatelly no, it creates folder under /root/PEAR and installs everything there

Comment: Yes you are right, the root of the cause was file .pearrc in /root, when deleted it works like expected.